# Prove that $\sum_{r=0}^{n} r \binom{n}{r}^2 = \frac{n}{2} \binom {2n}{n}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

My attempt
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} r \times \frac nr \left[\binom {n-1}{r-1} \right]^2$$
$$=n\sum _{r=0}^{n} \left [\binom {n-1}{r-1}\right]^2$$

The square on the binomial coefficient is throwing me off, otherwise it would have been easier to proceed. I don’t know what to do with that square.

Edit: As pointed out in the comment, i managed to find out $$\sum_{r=0}^n (\binom nr )^2 = \binom {2n}{n}$$

But using this in the above expression isn’t giving me the right answer. Am I supposed to make a modification to the limits in the sigma function?

Comment: *Hint:* binomial coefficients have a symmetry: $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$. Try rewriting the sum using a product of both types in each term.

Comment: $r\binom{n}r^2=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}r$, not $n\binom{n-1}{r-1}^2$. And you can usefully rewrite that as $n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{n-r}$

Comment: @Aditya: I got it by doing the algebra correctly: $$\begin{align*}r\binom{n}r^2&=n\cdot\frac{r}n\cdot\binom{n}r\cdot\binom{n}r\\&=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}r\end{align*}$$

Comment: Be careful of the sum limits.  Better omit $r=0$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so how do I sum that expression? I know the sum for $\binom {n}{r-1} \binom nr = \binom {2n} {n-1}$ but not with $n-1$

Comment: Given $n$ google employees and $n$ apple employees, pick a combined team of $n$ with the captain from google

Comment: @Empy2 is it $\binom {2n-1} {n-1}$? And how is that related to this problem?

Comment: @Aditya: It should be clear that you just need to compute $\sum_r\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}r$ and multiply by $n$. $\binom{n-1}{r-1}=\binom{n-1}{n-r}$, so you can compute $\sum_r\binom{n}r\binom{n-1}{n-r}$ instead. Imagine that you have $n$ women and $n-1$ men, and you want to pick a team of $n$ people from this pool of $2n-1$ people. $\binom{n}r\binom{n-1}{n-r}$ is the number of ways to pick a team with $r$ women. Summing over $r$ gives you the number of possible teams, but you can calculate that directly: how many teams of $n$ can be formed from a pool of $2n-1$ people?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495428/evaluating-sum-of-a-combination-series) answer your question? (also [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77664), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096873), more general [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3631429)...)

Comment: Pick $r$ from google, omit $r$ of the $n$ apple, then make one of the $r$ googles captain.  Or pick $n$ from the combined $2n$, pick a captain from them, anf half the time the captain turns out to be from google

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symmetry is the key. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^nr\binom{n}{r}^2&=\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)\binom{n}{r}^2\tag{1}\\
&=n\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}^2-\sum_{r=0}^nr\binom{n}{r}^2\\
\end{align*}
where we changed in the right-hand sum of (1) the order of summation $r\to n-r$.
We already know according to OPs calculation:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}^2=\binom{2n}{n}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

From (1) and (2) we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{r=0}^nr\binom{n}{r}^2}&=\frac{n}{2}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}^2
\color{blue}{=\frac{n}{2}\binom{2n}{n}}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

Comment: Shouldn’t the limits also change if you are replacing $r\to n-r$?

Comment: @Aditya: Let's consider for example the index range with $n=5$. We have the index sequence $(0,1,2,3,4,5)=(r)_{0\leq r\leq 5}$. Reverting the order of summation gives the index sequence $(5,4,3,2,1,0)=(5-r)_{0\leq r\leq 5}$. In both cases $0\leq r\leq 5$.